# ESlint Maximum call stack size exceeded Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, eslintrc

When i try run: `npm run dev`

console throw this:

```
[eslint] Maximum call stack size exceeded
Occurred while linting C:\project\src\plugins\three\threejs.js:4
Rule: "vue/max-len"
```

I have try already deleting `node_modules`, and add `/* eslint-disable */` on top of threejs.js file. But this didn`t help

Comment: Can you post the contents of "C:\project\src\plugins\three\threejs.js"?

Comment: @JasonLandbridge, its just plugin code, nothing special. But i add /* eslint-disable */ on top of this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
Change `eslintrc` file config.
Triggering error `vue/max-len`.
Fixed by changing `ignoreStrings: false` on `true`

See more in the [plugin documentation](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/max-len.html).